# Z-Normalized Euclidean Distance Derivation

Tags: distance, z-score, euclidean

I am going through this paper:

http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/PID4481997_extend_Matrix%20Profile_I.pdf

And on Page 4, it is claimed that the squared z-normalized euclidean distance between two vectors of equal length, `Q` and `T[i]`, (the latter of which is just the ith subsequence of a longer 1D array, `T`) can be calculated from:

[image]

Here, `m` is the length of `Q` (or `T[i]`), `mu_Q` is the mean of `Q`, `M_T[i]` is the mean for the ith subsequence of `T`, `sigma_Q` is the standard deviation of `Q`, `sigma_T[i]` is the standard deviation for the ith subsequence of `T`, and `Q.T[i]` is the dot product between `Q` and `T[i]`.

I am attempting to derive this equation from first principals but can't see to reconcile the final steps:

[image]

In this case, the summation loops through each element of either `T[i]` or `Q`. Also, recall that:

[image]

I've gotten as close as this but it's not quite right:

[image]

**A semi-related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296292/pearson-correlation-and-metric-properties).**

Comment: I hate to say it, but 99% of your problem seems to stem from a truly awful notation (for which we may blame the paper, evidently).  This algebra has been done over and over again in literally hundreds of posts here: it comes down to the fact that the sum of the residuals relative to the mean is zero.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to one of the hundreds of posts that demonstrates that logic? I've searched for a week and haven't come across anything remotely close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I research the MP paper 1 and 2. And I know your pain !!

[image]

Comment: Your second to the last step is wrong. After evaluating the average value you should drop the "sum" symbol in your equation. That's why you got an extra m.

Comment: My steps are equivalent to the below [ Here's a straightforward way. ]
I prove that [ (d_i,j)^2 = ~ ] not [ (d_i,j) = ~ ].
If you read the matrix profile paper carefully and know the dot product between subsequences [ t_i+k ] and [ t_j+k ] , you will know your point is wrong.

Comment: In case others stumble across this, the STUMPY Python library now offers an efficient implementation for computing matrix profiles https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (along with other tools in that ecosystem)

Comment: I have seen the python library, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward way. Let $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ be $m$-vectors.

Let  $\mu_1=\frac 1m\sum_{k=1}^m u_k$ and $\mu_2=\frac 1m\sum_{k=1}^m v_k$ denote their means.

Let  $\sigma_1^2=\frac 1m\sum_{k=1}^m (u_k-\mu_1)^2$ and $\sigma_2^2=\frac 1m\sum_{k=1}^m (v_k-\mu_2)^2$ denote their standard deviations. This rewrites as $\sigma_1^2=\frac 1m\left|\left| \mathbf u-\mu_1\mathbf 1   \right| \right|^2$, hence $m=\left| \left| \frac{\mathbf u-\mu_1\mathbf 1}{\sigma_1} \right| \right|^2=\left| \left| \frac{\mathbf v-\mu_2\mathbf 1}{\sigma_2} \right| \right|^2$

The squared $z$-normalized Euclidean distance between $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$  is $$\begin{align}\left|\left|\frac{\mathbf u-\mu_1\mathbf 1}{\sigma_1} -\frac{\mathbf v-\mu_2\mathbf 1}{\sigma_2}\right|\right|^2
&= \left| \left| \frac{\mathbf u-\mu_1\mathbf 1}{\sigma_1} \right| \right|^2+\left| \left| \frac{\mathbf v-\mu_2\mathbf 1}{\sigma_2} \right| \right|^2 -\frac{2}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} \langle \mathbf u-\mu_1\mathbf 1, \mathbf v-\mu_2\mathbf 1\rangle \\
&= 2m-\frac{2}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} \left(\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v \rangle-\mu_2 \sum_{k=1}^mu_k -\mu_1 \sum_{k=1}^mv_k + \mu_1 \mu_2m  \right)\\
&=2m-\frac{2}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} \left(\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle -\mu_2m\mu_1 - \mu_1m\mu_2+\mu_1 \mu_2m \right)\\
&=2m \left(1-\frac{1}{m\sigma_1 \sigma_2}\left(\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle -m\mu_1\mu_2\right) \right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Lmao at the downvote...